# How to fetch specific data from API json response in Python

Tags: python, json, api

I am a network engineer with keen interest in network automation. I am beginner in suing python for automation.

I have recently written a code to send a GET API query to one device and fetch the details of network objects and it has given me a lot of information which I actually do not need.

I want to know how can I parse or fetch specific data from json response.

for instance from the following response:

```
{'links': {'self': 'https://fmcrestapisandbox.cisco.com/api/fmc_config/v1/domain/e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f/object/networks?offset=0&limit=25&expanded=true'}, 'items': [{'links': {'self': 'https://fmcrestapisandbox.cisco.com/api/fmc_config/v1/domain/e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f/object/networks/005056BB-0B24-0ed3-0000-893353264061', 'parent': 'https://fmcrestapisandbox.cisco.com/api/fmc_config/v1/domain/e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f/object/networkaddresses'}, 'type': 'Network', 'value': '10.0.0.0/8', 'overridable': True, 'description': 'test api put wih postman ', 'id': '005056BB-0B24-0ed3-0000-893353264061', 'name': '10.0.0.0_8', 'metadata': {'timestamp': 1602974037876, 'lastUser': {'name': 'akankshu_a'}, 'domain': {'name': 'Global', 'id': 'e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f'}, 'ipType': 'V_4', 'parentType': 'NetworkAddress'}}, {'links': {'self': 'https://fmcrestapisandbox.cisco.com/api/fmc_config/v1/domain/e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f/object/networks/005056BB-0B24-0ed3-0000-893353272647', 'parent': 'https://fmcrestapisandbox.cisco.com/api/fmc_config/v1/domain/e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f/object/networkaddresses'}, 'type': 'Network', 'value': '10.10.210.0/24', 'overridable': False, 'description': ' ', 'id': '005056BB-0B24-0ed3-0000-893353272647', 'name': '10.10.210.0_24', 'metadata': {'timestamp': 1598427295586, 'lastUser': {'name': 'akankshu_a'}, 'domain': {'name': 'Global', 'id': 'e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f'}, 'ipType': 'V_4', 'parentType': 'NetworkAddress'}}
```

I want to fetch only this:

```
'type': 'Network', 'value': '10.10.210.0/24', 'overridable': False, 'description': ' ', 'name': '10.10.210.0_24'
```

Kindly help.

Regards
Akankshu

***Additonal Comments:***

I have used the following code to fetch the desired result:

Hi Bill, I did the following to get the desired output, however, I need to know how can I format it back to json so that I can you POST method to push it to device via API.........import json

data_txt = """
{"links": {"self": "https://fmcrestapisandbox.cisco.com/api/fmc_config/v1/domain/e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f/object/networks?offset=0&limit=25&expanded=true"}, "items": [{"links": {"self": "https://fmcrestapisandbox.cisco.com/api/fmc_config/v1/domain/e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f/object/networks/005056BB-0B24-0ed3-0000-893353264061", "parent": "https://fmcrestapisandbox.cisco.com/api/fmc_config/v1/domain/e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f/object/networkaddresses"}, "type": "Network", "value": "10.0.0.0/8", "overridable": "True", "description": "test api put wih postman ", "id": "005056BB-0B24-0ed3-0000-893353264061", "name": "10.0.0.0_8", "metadata": {"timestamp": 1602974037876, "lastUser": {"name": "akankshu_a"}, "domain": {"name": "Global", "id": "e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f"}, "ipType": "V_4", "parentType": "NetworkAddress"}}, {"links": {"self": "https://fmcrestapisandbox.cisco.com/api/fmc_config/v1/domain/e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f/object/networks/005056BB-0B24-0ed3-0000-893353272647", "parent": "https://fmcrestapisandbox.cisco.com/api/fmc_config/v1/domain/e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f/object/networkaddresses"}, "type": "Network", "value": "10.10.210.0/24", "overridable": "False", "description": " ", "id": "005056BB-0B24-0ed3-0000-893353272647", "name": "10.10.210.0_24", "metadata": {"timestamp": 1598427295586, "lastUser": {"name": "akankshu_a"}, "domain": {"name": "Global", "id": "e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f"}, "ipType": "V_4", "parentType": "NetworkAddress"}}]}
"""

json_obj = json.loads(data_txt)

json_obj.pop('links')

items = json_obj

pop_item=['links','id','metadata']
for val in pop_item:
for val2 in range(0,2):
json_obj['items'][val2].pop(val)
print(json_obj['items'])

However, I want to know how to convert it to json format so that I can use API POST method to push it to another device.

Comment: You can refer this article [Python API Tutorial: Getting Started with APIs](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-api-tutorial/)

Comment: your example response isn't properly formed. please fix that.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use a tool like [JSON Parser Online](http://json.parser.online.fr/) to make sure your JSON is formatted correctly for parsing. This is helpful when posting here because it gives people a reproducible example.

Once that's done, you can use Python's built-in `json` module to parse the JSON text into an object that you can navigate.

```
import json

data_txt = """
{"links": {"self": "https://fmcrestapisandbox.cisco.com/api/fmc_config/v1/domain/e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f/object/networks?offset=0&limit=25&expanded=true"}, "items": [{"links": {"self": "https://fmcrestapisandbox.cisco.com/api/fmc_config/v1/domain/e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f/object/networks/005056BB-0B24-0ed3-0000-893353264061", "parent": "https://fmcrestapisandbox.cisco.com/api/fmc_config/v1/domain/e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f/object/networkaddresses"}, "type": "Network", "value": "10.0.0.0/8", "overridable": "True", "description": "test api put wih postman ", "id": "005056BB-0B24-0ed3-0000-893353264061", "name": "10.0.0.0_8", "metadata": {"timestamp": 1602974037876, "lastUser": {"name": "akankshu_a"}, "domain": {"name": "Global", "id": "e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f"}, "ipType": "V_4", "parentType": "NetworkAddress"}}, {"links": {"self": "https://fmcrestapisandbox.cisco.com/api/fmc_config/v1/domain/e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f/object/networks/005056BB-0B24-0ed3-0000-893353272647", "parent": "https://fmcrestapisandbox.cisco.com/api/fmc_config/v1/domain/e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f/object/networkaddresses"}, "type": "Network", "value": "10.10.210.0/24", "overridable": "False", "description": " ", "id": "005056BB-0B24-0ed3-0000-893353272647", "name": "10.10.210.0_24", "metadata": {"timestamp": 1598427295586, "lastUser": {"name": "akankshu_a"}, "domain": {"name": "Global", "id": "e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f"}, "ipType": "V_4", "parentType": "NetworkAddress"}}]}
"""

json_obj = json.loads(data_txt)
```

Now you have an object with a 'links' section and an 'items' section. You can skip the links, since all the information you're after is in the items.

```
items = json_obj["items"]
```

From here you can either use an index to directly access the item you want, or loop over the list of items to get information from all (both) of them.

```
item = items[1] # just get the second item

# loop over all of the items
for item in items:
    print("Type:", item["type"])
    print("Value:", item["value"])
    print("Overridable:", item["overridable"])
    print("Description:", item["description"])
    print("Name:", item["name"])
```

Comment: Hi Bill, Thank you for wonderful explanation, however I would like to know which option to use in Json parser (String parse or JS eval)? Also, I want to know how can I fetch the data in dictionary format so that I can use "POST" method to push it to other similar device

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for all the help. Finally I figured out the way to make everything work, however, thanks for putting me on right path. Cheers